# Select All Row or Select All Column in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a grid of checkboxes that can be any number of rows or columns wide (it's a bad design I know, but we're replicating a legacy system).

[image]

The checkboxes with the pale yellow background will select all checkboxes in the row or column that they're adjacent to.

I normally have a bit of jQuery that'll do this sort of this for a single list of checkboxes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.master-checkbox').show();

    $('.master-checkbox').click(function () {
        $('.section-checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $('.section-checkbox').change(function () {
        var check = ($('.section-checkbox').filter(":checked").length == $('.section-checkbox').length);
        $('.master-checkbox').prop("checked", check);
    });
});
```

I could use the above code 4x to do the job I need, but as the rows and columns could (will) grow in size, does anyone know of a nifty way that I can add the same functionality to my checkboxes without having to duplicate the jQuery code 'n' times?

**[EDIT]**

The jQuery code I've included is the sort of thing I would use if doing this sort of thing with one column of checkboxes and one master checkbox.

For the moment, I've given the checkboxes on the top the classes 'master-sco-0' and 'master-sco-1' respectively and the two on the left I've given the classes 'master-sec-0' and 'master-sec-1'.  The 4 in the middle are (from left to right, top to bottom) 'sec-0 sco-0', 'sec-0 sco-1', 'sec-1 sco-0' and 'sec-1 sco-1'.

**[EDIT2]**

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3U44n/) of the problem.

**[EDIT3]**

Here's the final solution I came up with from Arun's answer.  I've included further triggering of change events to ensure the column/row master check boxes can react to other column/row master check boxes making changes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.cb-master-col').click(function () {
            var isMasterColChecked = this.checked;

            var tdMasterPosition = $(this).parent().index();

            var $table = $(this).closest('table');
            $table.find('td:nth-child(' + (tdMasterPosition + 1) + ') input.cb-child').each(function () {
                if (this.checked != isMasterColChecked) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', isMasterColChecked);
                    $(this).trigger('change');
                }
            });
        });

        $('.cb-master-row').click(function () {
            var isMasterRowChecked = this.checked;

            $(this).closest('tr').find('input.cb-child').each(function () {
                if (this.checked != isMasterRowChecked) {
                    $(this).prop('checked', isMasterRowChecked);
                    $(this).trigger('change');
                }
            });
        });

        $('.cb-child').change(function () {
            var $tr = $(this).closest('tr')
            $tr.find('input.cb-master-row').prop('checked', $tr.find('input.cb-child').not(':checked').length == 0);

            var tdChildPosition = $(this).parent().index();

            var $table = $(this).closest('table');
            var $ths = $table.find('thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(' + (tdChildPosition + 1) + ')');
            var $tds = $table.find('tbody td:nth-child(' + (tdChildPosition + 1) + ')');

            $ths.find('input.cb-master-col').prop('checked', $tds.find('input.cb-child').not(':checked').length == 0)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is there a class for the row master checkboxes

Comment: can you share a sample html

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your situation correctly ,a fiddle would be great

Comment: can you add an additional class like `row-master` for the left 2 and `col-master` for the top 2

Comment: Actually... I'm thinking it might be best to simply wrap my jQuery in a function and just call it once per row/column on page load.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I can add any classes and can change any of the HTML.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips see my answer below

Comment: I'm just heading home for the day, I might not be able to reply to anyone for the next 4 hours, thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can add an additional class like `row-master` for the left 2 and `col-master` for the top 2 also add a class `child` to other checkboxes

```
$('.col-master').click(function(){
    var idx = $(this).parent().index();
    $('table td:nth-child(' + (idx + 1) + ') input.child').prop('checked', this.checked)
})

$('.row-master').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input.child').prop('checked', this.checked)
});

$('.child').change(function(){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr')
    $tr.find('input.row-master').prop('checked', $tr.find('.child').not(':checked').length == 0);

    var idx = $(this).parent().index(), $tds = $('table td:nth-child(' + (idx + 1) + ')');
    $tds.find('input.col-master').prop('checked', $tds.find('input.child').not(':checked').length == 0)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kKYgA/)

Comment: That's pretty close, I've added a jsfiddle to show how the current behaviour works, would it be easy to do a similar bit of jQuery to cause the master checkboxes to unselect/select when a row is disrupted?

Comment: +1 Thanks, that looks to behave perfectly! You are indeed a jQuery god.

Answer (score 1):

If having custom attributes is not a problem, you can use html5 data-* attribute to store row/column count like this

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td> ALL</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="col_check" data-col="1" /></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="col_check" data-col="2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="row_check" data-row="1" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-col="1" data-row="1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-col="2" data-row="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="row_check" data-row="2" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-col="1" data-row="2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-col="2" data-row="2" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="row_check" data-row="3" /></td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-col="1" data-row="3" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-col="2" data-row="3" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then target the master checkboxes by their className

```
$('.col_check').on('click', function(){
    var colnum = $(this).attr('data-col');
    $('input[data-col='+colnum+']').prop('checked', this.checked);
});

$('.row_check').on('click', function(){
    var rownum = $(this).attr('data-row');
    $('input[data-row='+rownum+']').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9GYDS/

Comment: That's along the lines of what I need, each of the checkboxes in the grid would also need to clear/select the master checkboxes too.  I;ve included a jsfiddle with behaviour if it's any help.

Comment: Arun's answer is seemingly better, use that